# Return a 16 digit UUID in which at 7,11,15 and 19th position i need to add a hiphen

Tags: javascript

I need to write a function which returns a 16 digit UUID but at the at 7,11,15 and 19th position I need to include a hiphen.

I am trying out the functions on Stack Over flow but not getting the desired result. Please help me out.

Comment: Can you also add those *functions on Stack Over flow* that you tried? We can start from there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this function -

```js
     private uuid() {
       let random_string = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
      random_string += Math.floor(Math.random() * 15).toString(16);
      if (i === 7 || i === 11 || i === 15 || i === 19) {
        random_string += '-';
      }
    }
    return random_string;
  }
```

Comment: Your random values will never have an F.